# Angular 4 packed in PhoneGap app shows blank screen

Tags: angular, cordova, angular-cli, phonegap-build

I wonder if anyone has had the same problem. I have a project based on Angular 4 using angular cli which works fine in web browsers. When I pack it in the cloud service of Adobe `build.phonegap.com` and install it on my Android tablet it shows blank screen.

I made an experiment creating a new angular cli project and with no any changes packing it directly in `build.phonegap.com` and the result is the same - blank screen when open the installed app in the tablet.

The very scarce information on the internet I found was regarding the `<base href="/">` but changing its path didn't help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found where the problem is. I had to update the file `polyfills.ts` in order to provide more robust polyfills for the mobile web view rendering engines used by Cordova / PhoneGap. So, in `polyfills.ts` I changed the line:

`import 'core-js/es6/reflect';`

into

`import 'core-js/es6';`

and this way providing the entire `es6` polyfills. This was enough for the brand new `angular cli` project. For my main project I had to include the line:

`import 'core-js/client/shim';`

which provides even more polyfills.

Now, I know that in order to optimize performance, it could be good to know the precise polyfills needed for the particular rendering engines and to include only those ones.

So to sumarize: I changed the `polyfills.ts` accordingly, and built the project using the following command:

`ng build --base-href . --prod`

Answer (score 0):

that's correct.

The issues is because of

```
<base href="/">
```

If you open up the console, you would see 404 not found on resources.

To solve the issue 
use

build using

```
ng build --base -href .
```

This dist folder should go in cordova.

Comment: There must have been such a problem in the past if everybody suggest it, but currently it doesn't work. I tryed it on a brand new unmodified angular-cli project.

Comment: u changed base-href to . ?

Comment: I built it running "ng build --base-href ." Later in the index.html it was <base href="."> So all went as planned but... no luck.

Comment: what's the error than ? i.e open in chrome developer tools & what is the error ?

Comment: Here comes my greater problem  - I was unable to pair my Android tablet with the desktop chrome, even though the USB debugging is enabled in the Developer options in the tablet. So work in the dark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156215/discussion-between-vivanov-and-parth-ghiya).

Answer (score -1):

I think you will find the following video explanation very helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiIGcmHtDDE

I've used the cordova cli for project configuration and it helped me a lot.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

As for the blank screen, using of "" helped indeed.